Open, connected, bounded set with nice boundary is locally on one side of the boundary
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be open, connected, and bounded. We assume that the boundary $\partial\Omega$ is locally the graph of a continuous (or differentiable) function, i.e., for all $x_0 \in \partial\Omega$ there are a rotation $Q\in \mathbb R^{n,n}$,
an open set $U$ with $x_0\in U$, and a function $h: (QU)'\to \mathbb  R$ such that
$$
\partial \Omega \cap U = Q^{-1} graph(h),
$$
where $(QU)'= \{ (x_1\dots x_{n-1}): \ x\in QU\}$.
Does this imply that locally the set $\Omega$ is on one side of the boundary?
I.e.,
after rotation the set is locally above (or below) the graph of a continuous function. In the notation above this means
$$
Q(\Omega \cap U) \subset \{y\in \mathbb R^n: \ y_n > h(y_1 \dots y_{n-1}) \}
\quad
\text{ or } 
\quad
Q(\Omega \cap U) \subset \{y\in \mathbb R^d: \ y_n < h(y_1 \dots y_{n-1}) \}.
$$
I suspect the answer to be 'yes', but have difficulty finding a proof.
For $n=2$ this should follow from the Jordan curve theorem.
The context is that some authors define bounded $C^{m,\alpha}$ domains in $\mathbb R^n$ as
open, connected, and bounded sets that are locally above the graph of a $C^{m,\alpha}$
function. So the question is, whether/why 'domain is locally above the graph' can be replaced by 'boundary is locally equal to the graph'.
Edit: In Adams' book on Sobolev spaces it is mentioned that the answer to this question is yes, without any hints or references.

For differentiable functions, you can estimate the boundary near a point on it with a hyperplane to within some sufficiently small $\epsilon$. This can be used to define sides and to show that $\Omega$ can lie on one side only. When the function is only continuous, the proof is more difficult, but is essentially the proof of the Jordan curve theorem in higher dimensions.

Do you have a reference? I would hope that here the proof is easier, as we already know that $\Omega$ is not all of $\mathbb R^d$.

If $\Omega$ were all of $\Bbb R^d$, the proof would be trivial, as there is no boundary to worry about. So that isn't much help. Unfortunately, I do not have a reference, I was just recalling ancient memories (which is why there isn't much detail.)
